# Excel - Sum certain range from pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel ***pivot table*** that looks like the following:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/33cu3vc.png]

Is there any way I can create a formula that will calculate the sales$ for a particular product at a particular store for a particular date range? I.e. Store X Aug 3-Aug 5 for product 2

Comment: If you don't want to use the built-in functionality of the pivot table (i.e. setting filters), please explain how you would like excel to behave.  Would you like totals for every 3 day period where data exists?  Would you like to type in a date range without using any menus?  How would you like to select which stores to display?

Comment: My pivot table draws information from an external reporting source

What I want to do is be able to easily pull in the sales amount for a particular store by specifying/entering a date range and product #

Answer (score 2):

Yes, three ways.

**1)** This is easiest using the pivot table rather than a formula. Filter the pivot table by store and your date range. Add the grand total row.

**2)** To do this with a formula I would suggest converting your pivot table to a standard range and using SUMIFS.

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C10,A2:A10,"=X",B2:B10,">"&"START_DATE",B2:B10,"<"&"END_DATE")
```

**3)** Finally, you could use subtotals in your pivot table to show everything at once.

Design > Layout > Subtotals > Show All Subtotals.

Then right click on a date in you pivot table, click Group, and select a grouping such as Months.

Comment: I'm actually looking to be able to pull this for different periods and stores and don't want to have to filter every time.

Comment: The sumifs formula can be used on a pivotable without conversions, just ensure that GETPIVOTDATA is disabled (or manually enter the ranges). This is what I would do. An alternative is to write a macro to automatically filter the table for your specified date range.